# how to properly change an interface after it has been implemented by many classes? java

Tags: java

I have an

```
public interface DoIt {
    void dosomething (int i, double x);
    int dosomethingelse (String s);
}
```

some class that implement it is `class_of_a` etc...
and i want to add an new method in the interface lets say `diditwork(int x);`
How am i suppose to do that while avoiding the problems of recompiling or whatever problem that might be ? What would be the new hierarchy ?

Comment: Is this new method should be implemented by existing classes? If not, then it doesn't make sense to add to interface. If needed, then we can't avoid re-compiling implemented classes.

Comment: Looking at the JDK's precedent with `SortedSet` and `NavigableSet`...there's not going to be a _nice_ way to deal with this. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a new interface and extend the old interface, something like:

```
interface DoIt2 extends DoIt
{
    // void doSomething(int i, double x);
    // int doSomethingelse(String s);
    void didItWork(int x);
}
```

Comment: why do you need the first 2 methods in DoIt2 ?

Comment: if DoIt2 extends DoIt why would you put there DoIt's methods?

Answer (score 2):

you can extend your existing Interface like this:

```
interface DoItMore extends DoIt {  diditwork(int x);  }
```

so you will have your old interface for low level Classes and your new Interface for high level. Then you have to change the used Interface in your High level class.

Answer (score -1):

create another interface and let the given class implement both interfaces

e.g.

```
public interface DoIt { 
    void dosomething(int i, double x);
    int dosomethingelse(String s);
}
```

and new interface

```
public interface CheckIt {
    boolean diditwork(int x);
}
```

classes without necessity to check would implement only DoIt interface, classes with necessity to check would implement also CheckIt interface